# IOS7 innerWidth & Co. gone bonkers?

Tags: javascript, ios7

Since IOS7 came out, innerWidth/outerWidth seem to be behaving strangely as can be seen here

Without viewport tag

- http://headjs.com/test/responsive.html

With viewport tag

- http://headjs.com/test/responsive-viewport.html

Especially in portrait mode ..it's reporting: `innerWidth:980 / outerWidth:768`

Watch out Tardis, IOS is after you !

Anyone got an idea on what's going on here, insights, or workarounds (cross-platform of course, not apple centric) ?

..up to IOS6 things worked fine as far as measurements went. Now in portrait mode it's reporting that it's bigger on the inside than the outside !?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `head` element and you'll be right as rain:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: I'll test it, but that's not really an excuse for measurements to be off to such a degree, especially since all worked fine up to ios6. I mean look at the portrait mode ..it's frikkin bigger on the inside than the outside (c) Dr. Who ^^

Comment: If you have an issue with it, file a radar with Apple. I think you were rely on something that happened to work, but not by design. You should always use the viewport meta tag if you're looking to support mobile devices in your responsive layouts.

Comment: As far as i know the viewport tag is recommended to be able to customize layout, but not something required. I agree on the "should", but it's not something ppl always "can"

Comment: To be fair to Apple, they have documented that the [default viewport width is 980px](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW33) for iOS.

Comment: innerWidth:980 / outerWidth:768 ..ok for the 980, but someone explain the 768 to me :)

Comment: Same doc linked to early, from the section "**How Safari Infers the Width, Height, and Initial Scale**": "_If you set only some of the properties, then Safari on iOS infers the values of the other properties with the goal of fitting the webpage in the visible area. For example, if just the initial scale is set, then the width and height are inferred. Similarly, if just the width is set, then the height and initial scale are inferred, and so on. If the inferred values do not work for your webpage, then set more viewport properties._" 768px is the portrait width of the iPad.

Comment: Adding the tag resolves some problems. In landscape mode innerWidth: 1024 / screen.width: 768 ..looks like they messed up and/or watched too much Dr Who

Comment: When you switch to landscape mode, the viewport rotates 90°, but the screen doesn't, so screen width runs top to bottom and gives 768px. Check screen.height and it'll be 1024px. However, since the viewport _did_ rotate, its width is now the same as screen.height, that is, 1024px.

Comment: ...getting there: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/10/initialscale1_m.html

Comment: Funny that. `initial-scale` is set in my answer.

Comment: You didn't read the article ..the culprit (at least of one of the problems) is device-width